# twoside translation with reledpar, page numbering on every "half" page

Tags: double-sided, reledmac, reledpar

I would like to print a translation of a text along with the original text. The result shall meet the following conditions:

1. The document shall be two-columned, with the original text in the left column and the translation in the right column.
2. The paragraphs of the two columns shall be aligned to each other, so that a new paragraph of the translation starts where the corresponding paragraph of the original starts.
3. Every a5-page shall be numbered, just as it would be in a a5-twoside document. (The pdf-document shall be used to print an A4-brochure that is de facto a A5-book after being folded in the middle.)

To meet the first two conditions, I use

```
\documentclass[a4, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
      ... the original text, with paragraphs chunked by \pstart and \pend ...
    \end{Leftside}

    \begin{Rightside}
       ... the translation, with paragraphs chunked by \pstart and \pend ...
    \end{Rightside}
  \end{pairs}

\end{document}
```

and it fulfills the first two conditions perfectly. But I do not find a way to achieve the third condition. (In the ME above the page numbers appear in the middle of the a4-page.) Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: why not really use a5 paper and the \Pages tools of reledpar ?

Comment: Well - that's it. Somehow I was stuck to a solution with pair and \Columns and did not consider \Pages for some strange reason.

Comment: I really recommand you this solution, especially because of separating footnotes.

Comment: Ps : you should load reledmac _after_ having change the geometry with the geometry package, and you should use the "hack" mentionned on § 6.11.5 of reledmac handbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for documenting this in case of someone else faces a similar problem: I achieved what I wanted with the hint of Maïeul and with the use of the package pgfpages, the working minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[prevpgnotnumbered=empty]{reledpar}

%set the a5-pages together on a4 (uncomment the following two lines to   
%make the document printable as brochure - which still needs to add some 
%blank pages at the right positions, too)
\usepackage{pgfpages}
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, landscape]

\begin{document}
  \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \input{original.tex}       
    \end{Leftside}

    \begin{Rightside}
      \input{translation.tex}
    \end{Rightside} 
  \end{pages}
  \Pages
\end{document}
```